# SAP Hana Vora : Unable to query vora tables

Tags: vora

I am trying to query the vora table `select * from table_name` but geting below error...i am using SAP Hana Vora 1.2...

Caused by:

```
sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error. (schema error: schema "spark_velocity" does not exist (c++ exception)) at 
sap.hanavora.jdbc.driver.HLMessage.buildException(HLMessage.java:88) at 
sap.hanavora.jdbc.driver.tcp.TcpDriver.checkErrorsV2(TcpDriver.java:488) at 
sap.hanavora.jdbc.driver.tcp.TcpDriver.sendMessageCheckAndReciveRespone(TcpDriver.java:520) at 
sap.hanavora.jdbc.driver.tcp.TcpDriver.execute(TcpDriver.java:178) at 
sap.hanavora.jdbc.HLStatement.executeHelper(HLStatement.java:37) at 
sap.hanavora.jdbc.HLStatement.executeQuery(HLStatement.java:22) at 
sap.hanavora.jdbc.AbstractHLStatement.execute(AbstractHLStatement.java:55) at 
com.sap.spark.vora.client.jdbc.VoraJdbcClient.execute(VoraJdbcClient.scala:559) at 
com.sap.spark.vora.client.jdbc.VoraJdbcClient.executeSetSchema(VoraJdbcClient.scala:537) at 
com.sap.spark.vora.client.jdbc.VoraJdbcClient.liftedTree1$1(VoraJdbcClient.scala:143)
```

Could you please help me in clearing the vora catalogs.

Is there any way to clear vora catalog on SAP Hana Vora 1.2 ???? or to restart vora catalog on SAP Hana Vora 1.2???

Thanks, Akash

Comment: Could you provide the full error log? In order to delete tables from the catalog you can use the `drop table` command after the tables have been loaded into the local Spark Context via `REGISTER` command.

Comment: Hi Frank,  I setup Vora 1.2 on 5 nodes cluster. I want to know how many minimum nodes require to setup Vora 1.2? is it possible to setup it on single node?

Comment: I have a similar problem. By now there are multiple broken tables cluttering the catalog. If I try to remove one, it cannot find it. When I try to create a new table with the same name it says there would already be one. I can also see the tables in the vora-tools data browser. So it would be nice to be able to just reset the catalog or purge a specific table.